# linux redhat why resolve.conf is change

Tags: dns, file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux, resolv.conf

I have a *very strange issue* in my linux machine - redhat 6.7 version

when I update my resolve.conf file as the following:

```
 options attempts:2
 options timeout:1
 search usa.Pe.corp  tedcruz.usa.fb.corp
 nameserver 10.9.145.145
 nameserver 10.9.100.103
 nameserver 43.11.0.14
```

after **service network restart** I get different resolve.conf file as the following

```
 options attempts:2
 options timeout:1
 search usa.Pe.corp 
 nameserver 10.9.145.145
```

please advice how to **disable**/**block** the resolve.conf file from any changing?

please advice why the file is change after **network restart** or after **reboot**

Comment: You already got an answer on unix.stackexchange.com. You're not happy with it?

Comment: [Preserving changed in resolv.conf across reboots with resolvconf](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230572)